# unable to uninstall and reinstall R on centos

Tags: linux, r, centos

I am trying to uninstall R in centos. I have tried

```
sudo rpm -e R.x86_64
>error: %preun(R-2.13.0-2.el6.rf.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 1

sudo yum remove R
>Failed:
  R.x86_64 0:2.13.0-2.el6.rf 

R
>R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10) -- "Spring Dance"
Copyright (C) 2014 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.
```

Iam unable to uninstall R its failing when i try with yum and rpm, later when i try R again it runs R as above. Please help how to uninstall R in centos.

I have deleted the R directory due to that R execution is not working, but the reinstallation of R is also not working., I have to reinstall R again to install some of the packages which were not working earlier, please find the steps below:

```
$sudo rm -rf /usr/lib64/R ** deleted the R directory


$sudo rpm -ivh http://mirror.chpc.utah.edu/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm


$sudo yum  -y  –enablerepo=epel  install  R  R-devel
>Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security

$sudo yum  install RLoaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
>Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink                                            | 5.3 kB     00:00     
 * base: centos.aol.in
 * epel: mirror-fpt-telecom.fpt.net
 * extras: centos.aol.in
 * rpmforge: mirror-fpt-telecom.fpt.net
 * updates: centosmirror.go4hosting.in
Cloudera-cdh4                                            |  951 B     00:00     
base                                                     | 3.7 kB     00:00     
cloudera-impala                                          |  951 B     00:00     
extras                                                   | 3.4 kB     00:00     
rpmforge                                                 | 1.9 kB     00:00     
updates                                                  | 3.4 kB     00:00     
Setting up Install Process
Package R-3.1.0-5.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

$R
>/usr/bin/R: line 236: /usr/lib64/R/etc/ldpaths: No such file or directory

$ rpm -q --scripts R
postinstall scriptlet (using /bin/sh):
/sbin/install-info /usr/share/info/R-FAQ.info.gz /usr/share/info/dir 2>/dev/null
/sbin/install-info /usr/share/info/R-admin.info.gz /usr/share/info/dir 2>/dev/null
/sbin/install-info /usr/share/info/R-exts.info.gz /usr/share/info/dir 2>/dev/null
/sbin/install-info /usr/share/info/R-intro.info.gz /usr/share/info/dir 2>/dev/null
/sbin/install-info /usr/share/info/R-lang.info.gz /usr/share/info/dir 2>/dev/null
/sbin/ldconfig
preuninstall scriptlet (using /bin/sh):
/sbin/install-info --delete R-FAQ /usr/share/info/dir 2>/dev/null
/sbin/install-info --delete R-admin /usr/share/info/dir 2>/dev/null
/sbin/install-info --delete R-exts /usr/share/info/dir 2>/dev/null
/sbin/install-info --delete R-intro /usr/share/info/dir 2>/dev/null
/sbin/install-info --delete R-lang /usr/share/info/dir 2>/dev/null
postuninstall program: /sbin/ldconfig

$ rpm --noscripts -e R
error: "R" specifies multiple packages:
  R-2.13.0-2.el6.rf.x86_64
  R-3.1.0-5.el6.x86_64
$ R
/usr/bin/R: line 236: /usr/lib64/R/etc/ldpaths: No such file or directory
```

With the new commands.. not sure what does sudo rpm --noscripts -e --allmatches R do?

```
$ sudo rpm --noscripts -e --allmatches R
$ R
/usr/bin/R: line 236: /usr/lib64/R/etc/ldpaths: No such file or directory

$ sudo yum reinstall R
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Reinstall Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink                                            | 4.7 kB     00:00     
 * base: centos.aol.in
 * epel: mirror-fpt-telecom.fpt.net
 * extras: centos.aol.in
 * rpmforge: mirror-fpt-telecom.fpt.net
 * updates: centosmirror.go4hosting.in
Cloudera-cdh4                                            |  951 B     00:00     
base                                                     | 3.7 kB     00:00     
cloudera-impala                                          |  951 B     00:00     
extras                                                   | 3.4 kB     00:00     
rpmforge                                                 | 1.9 kB     00:00     
updates                                                  | 3.4 kB     00:00     
No Match for argument: R
Package(s) R available, but not installed.
Nothing to do

$ sudo rpm --noscripts -e --allmatches R
error: package R is not installed

$ R
/usr/bin/R: line 236: /usr/lib64/R/etc/ldpaths: No such file or directory
```

Current Output: -

```
$ type -p R
/usr/bin/R

$ sudo yum install R
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.aol.in
 * epel: epel.mirror.net.in
 * extras: centos.aol.in
 * rpmforge: mirror-fpt-telecom.fpt.net
 * updates: centosmirror.go4hosting.in
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package R.x86_64 0:3.1.0-5.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package      Arch              Version                   Repository       Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 R            x86_64            3.1.0-5.el6               epel             21 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install       1 Package(s)

Total download size: 21 k
Installed size: 0  
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
R-3.1.0-5.el6.x86_64.rpm                                 |  21 kB     00:00     
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
Warning: RPMDB altered outside of yum.
** Found 2 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
R-devel-3.1.0-5.el6.x86_64 has missing requires of R-core-devel = ('0', '3.1.0', '5.el6')
R-java-devel-3.1.0-5.el6.x86_64 has missing requires of R-core-devel = ('0', '3.1.0', '5.el6')
  Installing : R-3.1.0-5.el6.x86_64                                         1/1 
Unable to send message to PackageKit
  Verifying  : R-3.1.0-5.el6.x86_64                                         1/1 

Installed:
  R.x86_64 0:3.1.0-5.el6                                                        

Complete!

$ R
/usr/bin/R: line 236: /usr/lib64/R/etc/ldpaths: No such file or directory
```

How can we build the binary file which got deleted, it got installed but not building the file to execute R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does `rpm -q --scripts R` say the preun scriptlet is doing?

You can try to make that scriplet not fail.

Or, failing that or if the scriptlet isn't doing anything important, you can just run `rpm --noscripts -e R` to tell rpm not to run package scriptlets.

Use 'yum reinstall R` to reinstall R even though it is installed if that's what you want to do. (You shouldn't have just deleted random packaged files like that in any case. That doesn't help anything).

To work around that `error: "R" specifies multiple packages` problem you can (probably) use `rpm --noscripts -e --allmatches R`.

Edit: Including suggestions from the comments the final solution seems to have involved installing (and reinstalling) all the various R packages (R, R-devel, R-core, R-core-devel).

Comment: thanks.. I have deleted the R directory in lib64, not R iam unable to execute. I wanted to reinstall it again but thats not working.

Comment: i just did that, i have edited the above post, please look into it.. can you explain what does rpm --noscripts -e --allmatches R do..

Comment: `reinstall` was to work around the `Package R-3.1.0-5.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version` message from `yum`. Since you've now actually removed the package (though where the R "binary" is coming from I'm unsure of at the moment `type -p R` will tell you though) you now need to `yum install R` to install the package.

Comment: How can we build the binary file which got deleted, it got installed but not building the file to execute R. Please see the current output from the commands which you have given above..

Comment: Install the `R-core` and `R-core-devel` packages to fix those dependency problems. I have no idea if that will be enough to fix your R problems because your system is in a fairly confused state at the moment but that might be enough. You might want to run `rpm -Va` to find out what other problems with packages rpm tells you about (not all the things it will list are problems that need fixing though).

Comment: missing     /usr/bin/R,                                       Unsatisfied dependencies for R-devel-3.1.0-5.el6.x86_64:
 R-core-devel = 3.1.0-5.el6 is needed by R-devel-3.1.0-5.el6.x86_64
It shows R library missing, and I need to install R-core-devel to create dependency..

Comment: installed R-core and R-core-devel, still no go.. its not executing R from the $ prompt..

Comment: What does `rpm -Va` say now that you've installed those two packages? Are you still getting the same ldpaths error at this point? If rpm is complaining about `/usr/bin/R` being missing but `type -p R` says `/usr/bin/R` that's a bit odd (and it might be worth moving that file out of the way and then trying `yum reinstall R`).

Comment: Cool its working now after i installed R-core.. it has opened R... yeee.. thanks dear for your help!! @Etan please add this in the answer section so that I can mark it useful... thanks for you help... ;-)